# ontransitionend not binding after CSS translate3d

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms, translate3d

I'm implementing a scroll hijack of a page, and like to use the event handler ontransitionend, to track the end of a CSS3 transformation, translate3d.

However, I sometimes "lose" the event handler and it does not trigger ontransitionend.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

I don't want to use jQuery animations because they run slow, and set-timeout causes a lag/flicker. Not sure of other good ways to accomplish this effect.

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    .transition(all 1500ms ease); // LESS mixin w/ transition prefixes
}
.page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <section class="page target" id="One"></section>
        <section class="page target" id="Two"></section>
        <section class="page target" id="Three"></section>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</div>


var total_sections = $('.page.target').length;
var is_moving = false;

$(window).on({
    'DOMMouseScroll mousewheel': detectScroll
});

// transitionend, runs into = problems
$('.content, .footer').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
    is_moving = false;
});

function detectScroll (e) {
    if(is_moving) {
        return false;
    }
    is_moving = true;
    (function() { 
        scrollPage(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 'up' : 'down'); 
    })();
    // return false;
}

var curr_section = 0;   // we always start at top of page
function scrollPage(dir) {
    setTarget(curr_section, dir);
}

function setTarget(curr, dir) {
    var target;
    if(dir == 'up') {
        target = curr-1;
    }
    if(dir == 'down') {
        target = curr+1;
    }
    var h = $('.page.target').height();
    target = target * h * -1;

    is_moving = true;

    // jquery animations run slower than css3 transitions :(
    // $('.content, .footer').animate({
    //  'top': target
    // }, 50);

    $('.content, .footer').css({
        'transform': 'translate3d(0px, ' + target + 'px, 0px)'
    });
    // is_moving = false after transition ends

    // using settimeout to reset is_moving causes a "flicker" / jump
    // var transition_speed = 1600;
    // window.setTimeout(function(){
    //  is_moving = false;
    // }, transition_speed);

    // reset current section
    if(dir == 'up') {
        curr_section = curr_section-1;
    }
    if(dir == 'down') {
        curr_section = curr_section+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `transition` property not appear defined at `css` ?

Comment: i've applied css transitions with a LESS mixin with "all 1500ms ease" as well position relative applied to the .content element

Comment: _"applied css transitions with a LESS mixin with "all 1500ms ease" as well position relative applied to the .content element"_ Not appear at OP ? Return expected results when `transition` property added to `css` ?

Answer (score 0):

How about to switch from One to on?

`$('.content').on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend','.footer', function(e) { 
    is_moving = false; 
 });`

Comment: Thanks, that def was causing a bug (losing the event handler); however I'm still noticing a latency between end of animation, and waiting for the end of scroll... so transition end doesn't actually register until I stop scrolling my mouse. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm.. its tricky.. maybe.. if you will use jquery animation onstead of CSS3 you can instantly know when it ends... It is not the best solution but it will work 100%.

Comment: Next idea is to pack this function inside a Scroll event handler so it will check when its scrolling so you can use it twice, frst time without scrolling and then when its scrolled.. Just ideas..

Comment: Tried using jQuery animations, but they run much slower than pure CSS animations & the "jitter" on the page isn't acceptable for the experience. Let me test ontransitionend tied inside the scroll event... Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so figured out a solution if anyone else is experiencing this problem.

Essentially ontransitionend doesn't trigger until the user has completely stopped physically scrolling (so, on scroll end).

I ended up using the current section's offset top to determine whether or not the target was hit / animation is ended. However, encountered the same problem. Offset top during scroll would not update until I had physically stopped scrolling the mouse; I need something more responsive.

I ended up using .hide().show() on the current section, so continually updating the DOM and now offset().top updates during scroll (even while I'm still physically scrolling the mouse wheel).

It's a bit of hack, but it works.